# The modifier async is not valid for this item

Tags: c#, .net, io, windows-8, microsoft-metro

*This does not appear to be a duplicate of the many hundreds of other questions with the same error. I have looked at them all and have found them to be unrelated.*

I am making a little note app and am trying to read files from a directory. Following the MSDN example, I have the following code, but it is giving me an Error of:

---

> Error 1   The modifier 'async' is not valid for this
>   item  C:\Users\Jase\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\AppNameHere\AppNameHere\DataModel\AppNameHereDataSource.cs  192 9   AppNameHere

---

The code I have is:

```
    async public NotesDataSource()
    {
        StorageFolder documentsFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
        StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList =
            await documentsFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        outputText.AppendLine("Files:");

        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            if (file.FileType == "txt")
            {
                outputText.Append(file.Name + "\n");
            }
        }
        // lots of irrelevant code removed.
    }
```

---

I don't understand what's going on here. I followed everything to a "T". Can somebody please help?

Thank you!

Comment: What .NET Framework are you trying to target. `async` is only a keyword if an extension of the .NET Framework is installed and/or if you trying to target .NET Framework 4.5.  Please provide a link to the MSDN example.

Comment: It's for a Metro app in Windows 8 release preview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758323.aspx - and this error is not because Windows 8 is not finished yet (as I've been told many times) - because *many* other apps are reading from and writing to files in Metro apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can constructors be async](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async)

Comment: As per the duplicate question, you can't have an async constructor.

Comment: I am trying some suggestions in comments and answers and will be back shortly. Thanks all :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect. Look at it:

```
async public NotesDataSource()
```

Firstly, `async` has to come *after* the access modifier IIRC.

Secondly, either you're trying to create an async constructor (which you can't do) or you're trying to write a method without a return type (which is equally invalid).

Try this:

```
public async Task NotesDataSource()
```

That's if you meant it to be a method. If you want to *effectively* create an async constructor (or something close to it) you'd have to use an async static method:

```
public static async Task<NotesDataSource> CreateInstance()
{
    // Do async stuff here which fetches all the necessary data...

    return new NotesDataSource(...);
}
```

Comment: I can't use async after the access modifier. The compiler throws a hissy fit and tells me not to do it. So I tried putting it before the modifier and it got it working (more than it was, anyway)

Comment: @Jason: Well you've still got a compilation error, so it's not really working... you *should* have `async` after the access modifier, so I think you were just shifting the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Out of curiosity, (if you don't mind) I want to know : how do you manage to post so many answers (and comments) on daily basis? How much time do you spend on SO on an average?

Comment: @Nawaz: It's unclear - it's very much a background activity that I fit in between other things.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Surely, it is a background activity. I'm just wondering how it is even humanly possible to post so many answers; and on the top of it, you don't get bored of answering trivial questions. I must say you've great passion for C#. BTW, can I assume you spend almost 4 hours in total, daily?

Comment: @Nawaz: Again, it's hard to really say how much time I spend, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet: So you've no idea at all? Not even a range, something like, 4-6 hours, or something? :|.. or at least, how frequently you visit SO, or how many times, etc. Any such thing?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, not really. How much of your day is taken by breathing? It happens while you're doing other things. How many times do you breathe? It's not something you count.

Comment: @JonSkeet: But if you ask me, I can answer that doing some little calculation, for example, how many times do I breathe in a minute? How many minutes are there in a single day? That gives pretty much good idea of the number of breathe I take in a single day, doesn't it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12451/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-nawaz)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to place `async` *after* `public`:

```
public async NotesDataSource() 
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Compiler doesn't like that for some reason.

Comment: @Jason That's because in addition, you need to also implement one or the other of Jon Skeet's suggestions regarding Constructors and Static Methods.