# Awaiting Javascript callback while in constructor of c# object

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

My object in C# will call some JavaScript when constructed through the webbrowser control. The JavaScript will then call back to our c# code with a success or failure. I need to have the constructor of the C# object wait until the JavaScript returns the callback before it leaves the constructor. How would I go about doing this?

Essentially, I need to make sure that the object will always be properly initialized when created. This is dependent on the javascript calling back, which is at least slightly variable.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async

Comment: possible duplicate of [The modifier async is not valid for this item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997174/the-modifier-async-is-not-valid-for-this-item)

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot use `async/await` in a constructor, it still may be possible to make async JavaScript call-outs and wait for their completion, depending on what you actually do in JavaScript and inside the callback from JavaScript to C# . It's done by organizing a nested message loop, here's an [example taking this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050438/handling-ckeditor-async-calls-synchronously-with-c-sharp-winforms-webbrowser-con). Note, this may be dangerous as it may lead to code reentrancy.

That said, you still might be able to refactor your code to use `async/await` with one of the approaches described by Stephen Cleary in [his blog entry](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having an async constructor ([which is not possible with .NET, anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async) (thanks Servy) (and I don't think any other framework that allows for that is a sane framework, if such a thing exists)), you should:

- Construct your object in such a way that you don't depend on that Javascript call;
- Call whatever logic you need that will be done past .NET boundaries, and when the Javascript is done and responds...
- ... Call some `initialize()` method (name it like that or something similar).

You could have a flag in each instance telling whether is has already passed through the post-Javascript initialization, and some logic in your class so that its instances can only be considered to be in a valid, ready, usable state after that initialization step. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: It's way easier and safer to just rely on a factory method to create such objects, and ensure that callers can *only* construct an instance through such a method, rather than doing this.  This is described in the proposed duplicates as well.

Comment: So even if I had a factory, how would I ensure that the javascript has been properly been initialized? Given the variable nature of this action, the factory would either return null in the event of a non-properly initialized object, or the correct object in the event of a properly initialized one. I need to ensure that every time this object is requested, it will properly initialized (meaning the javascript will callback with a success).

Comment: You'd just have to do what I suggested inside the factory anyway. I think the factory pattern is tangential to the problem and solution here.

Comment: @Tim The factory would return a `Task<Whatever>`.  If the creation operation failed you could either have it mark the task as faulted, or you could have it continue to retry until it succeeded (or fault after a set number of attempts).

Comment: @Renan It's not, because By adding a facade you prevent consumers of the object from being given an object that isn't fully initialized, and yours relies on consumers using it properly to avoid problems.  With a factory method you ensure that they are not given the object until it is properly initialized.  That is a key difference.

Comment: @Servy from a consumer's point of view, yes, you are right. But my focus here is getting the object built and initialized. Inside your factory logic you have to do something other than using a factory, and there you are constrained by not being able to use an async constructor again. I agree that having a factory separating this object creation from consumers is a good practice, but in a really low level this is not the real solution to the OP's problem. It is something that makes the solution better, though.

Comment: @Renan At the end of the day you took the solution from the proposed duplicate, made it a bit worse, and posted it as an answer.  That important information about how such a factory method would be implemented is all still in the linked questions.