# get json from webservices with webclient without manipulate data in other method

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm developping on Windows phone 8 and I would like to know if it's possible to manipulate data in the same method when we call DownloadStringCompleted of WebClient?

```
private void DownloadDataFromWebService(String uri)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    private void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
        List<Category> listeCategories = r.Result;
    }
```

Thus, I would like to manage all code in only one method because I would like to return an object
For example,

```
private List<Category> GetCategories(String uri)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
        .....
        .....
        RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
        return (List<Category>) r.Result;
    }
```

Comment: you might take a look at the "new" asynchronous programming techniques (async/await) http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, due to magic TaskCompletionSource class, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) . To download:

```
async Task<List<object>> getCategories(String uri)
{
    var taskCompletionObj = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    var wc= new webClient();
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new URI(uri, Urikind.Absolute)) += (o, e) =>
    {
    taskCompletionObj.TrySetResult(e.Result);
    };
    string rawString = await taskCompletionObj.Task;
    RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rawString);
    return (List<Category>)r.Result; 
}
```

To use: `var x  = await getCategories(myURI);`

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

But now, how can I show the result of x? because when I show it in console, I have : System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
I need the result because I would like to convert a JSON to a object

Comment: Well, since `downloadString` method returns Task<string> this means that in the end, x will be a string. So x is your string that just came from the internet. Did you tried something like x.Result or I've just misunderstood it? Could you show me a stackTrace?

Comment: when I add "await" in front of downloadString method
=>      var x = await downloadString(myURI);
I must change the type of my method to Task<string>. But what I would like is return a List<Object>. So I removed the word await, and when I display the variable x, instead of displaying a JSON code, it displays me "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"
And when I do x.Result, thus "
var x = DownloadString(new Uri(stringBuilder.ToString()));
Debug.WriteLine(x.Result);"
The app crashes and there is no error...

Comment: In fact, the problem comes from "var x = await getCategories(myURI);" when I do this in a method, I must change the type of my method...

Comment: Yes, your calling method should be async too. As a rule you can consider every call of await.. should be made in an async method.

Comment: And how can I call this method in a constructor?

Comment: Well that's a problem, since constructor shouldn't be async. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async). But that is another subject. A solution would be to construct your object, and init it later, in an async init.

Comment: Thank you, I look on this side and I will keep you posted

Comment: Hello, so, I do it in a method instead of constructor and now it works :) thanks ana