# Call asynchronous method in constructor?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, constructor, visual-studio-2013, async-await

**Summary**: I would like to call an asynchronous method in a constructor. Is this possible?

**Details**: I have a method called `getwritings()` that parses JSON data. Everything works fine if I just call `getwritings()` in an `async` method and put `await` to left of it. However , when I create a `LongListView` in my page and try to populate it I'm finding that `getWritings()` is surprisingly returning `null` and the `LongListView` is empty.

To address this problem, I tried changing the return type of `getWritings()` to `Task<List<Writing>>` and then retrieving the result in the constructor via `getWritings().Result`. However, doing that ends up **blocking the UI thread.**

```
public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    List<Writing> writings;

    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getWritings();
    }

    private async void getWritings()
    {
        string jsonData = await JsonDataManager.GetJsonAsync("1");
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        JArray array = (JArray)obj["posts"];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            Writing writing = new Writing();
            writing.content = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "content");
            writing.date = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "date");
            writing.image = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "url");
            writing.summary = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "excerpt");
            writing.title = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "title");

            writings.Add(writing);
        }

        myLongList.ItemsSource = writings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the Constructor?

Comment: i have to call in somewhere otherwise how can i put my data in it any suggestion ?

Comment: i would do in the override async void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //here
}

Comment: Why do you need to access the result? Just call getWRitings() or whatever async method and _don't await it_. It won't be done when the constructor ends, but that's ok. Don't use its value there, instead - use its value in another method and call that.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i am doing right now and its done :)

Comment: @KBB I edited your very good question to hopefully make it even more useful to others. In doing so, I made some assumptions about your intent. So, if something doesn't look quite right now, please let me know. Of course, you can certainly edit further or even roll back my changes.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum In [Async OOP 2: Constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) in the concluding section *What NOT To Do,"* [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) argues that simply not awaiting an asynchronous method in a constructor is *not* a good idea.

Comment: @DavidRR that's cute, but I disagree with it, there are several cases where you want to perform an asynchronous action but not wait for it. Some cases include: sending analytics, actions where you want to perform I/O and wait for it later (think `<img` tags in browsers), and lazy actions. Generally, for 99% of cases it's good to avoid anything async in your constructor - but there is a strong case for that remaining 1%. Although in all cases above it's still a better idea to have the async method return a `Task` (and not void) and to store the task for future use.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum There is enough substance in your comment that I believe merits turning it into an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - DO NOT omit `await` so that you can call an `async` method from a constructor. Sooner or later, you'll write code that **deadlocks**. It is a bad habit to get into! A safe "fire and forget" solution is to create an async context and put that code into it. To run on a background thread: `Task.Run( async () => { /* await here */ } );`. To run on a UI thread, the appropriate method varies with different technologies (WPF, Maui, etc.)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The best solution is to acknowledge the asynchronous nature of the download and design for it.

In other words, decide what your application should look like while the data is downloading. Have the page constructor set up *that* view, and start the download. When the download completes *update* the page to display the data.

I have a blog post on [asynchronous constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) that you may find useful. Also, some MSDN articles; one on [asynchronous data-binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) (if you're using MVVM) and another on [asynchronous best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (i.e., you should avoid `async void`).

Comment: Too bad this answer applies specifically for UI code. I'm writing a Windows service that needs the constructor to load some things into memory, with the data coming from some async methods elsewhere.

Comment: @Ellesedil: This answer refers to MVVM specifically because this question was asking about MVVM specifically. My [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) is applicable to Win32 services, and you could ask your own question if you wish.

Comment: @Ellesedil I have the same problem as yours, I convert the async to sync and load it to memory... How do you solve this problem?

Comment: @Matus: First, explore redesigning the type so that it doesn't need asynchronous data at construction time. If that is untenable, then you can [inject an asynchronous factory](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary One of the more recent answers on here recommends `ContinueWith()` which I haven't seen before, but it seems in line with what some other languages do (thinking particularly of javascript here). Is that a newer solution that should work fine, or is it an older one you just haven't mentioned because it's not good?

Comment: @BVernon: It's an older one I didn't mention because it's not good. :)  `ContinueWith` is a [dangerous, low-level method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) (link to my blog). Modern code should use `await` instead. Side note: in JS, `then` should be replaced with `await`, too.

Answer (score 142):

You can also do just like this:

```
Task.Run(() => this.FunctionAsync()).Wait();
```

Note: Be careful about thread blocking!

Comment: how is that different from `FunctionAsync().Wait()`

Comment: You should be really careful, because it's not only blocking the thread, but can cause a deadlock (see here e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock). Especially easy to get a deadlock in winforms

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik While it is blocking the thread where the constructor is run, the `this.FunctionAsync()` call is executed in a different thread and upon completion the constructor is resumed. This pattern should actually work, while a direct `this.FunctionAsync().Wait()` would indeed deadlock. The gotcha: do not depend on specific thread affinity inside `FunctionAsync`, because its executing thread can be anything.

Comment: I have to say that I've tried all the solutions in this thread and this is the only one that worked. I have no idea why .ConfigureAwait(true/false).GetAwaiter().GetResult() or simply .Wait() would work differently from Task.Run(async () => await myAsyncMethod()).Wait(), but they did.

Comment: To add more context, I was executing an async method in the constructor of a web API controller, so there was no way to use different methods of instantiating the controller. The execution had to end before executing the API method called.

Comment: Don't ever call .Wait() or .Result as this is going to lock your app.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic - if your going to use Wait(), why have it asyncronous?

Comment: @Sam there's no such thing as an asynchronous constructor, if you don't wait the code likely won't execute at all, or the outcome is indeterminant given the context is exited already.

Comment: @Chrismarisic because sometimes you don't have a choice due to the fact that you didn't not design nor do you own the interface you're working with.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic this is about invoking async code inside a constructor, interfaces aren't relevant here.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic sry that reply was actually meant for Sam

Answer (score 106):

I'd like to share a pattern that I've been using to solve these kinds of problems. It works rather well I think. Of course, it only works if you have control over what calls the constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static async Task<MyClass> Create()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        await myClass.Initialize();
        return myClass;
    }

    private MyClass()
    {
    }

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Do whatever asynchronous work you need to do
    }
}
```

Basically what we do is we make the constructor private and make our own public `static async` method that is responsible for creating an instance of `MyClass`. By making the constructor private and keeping the static method within the same class we have made sure that no one could "accidentally" create an instance of this class without calling the proper initialization methods.

All the logic around the creation of the object is still contained within the class (just within a static method).

```
var myClass1 = new MyClass() // Cannot be done, the constructor is private
var myClass2 = MyClass.Create() // Returns a Task that promises an instance of MyClass once it's finished
var myClass3 = await MyClass.Create() // asynchronously creates and initializes an instance of MyClass
```

Implemented on the current scenario it would look something like:

```
public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public static async Task<Page2> Create()
    {
        var page = new Page2();
        await page.getWritings();
        return page;
    }

    List<Writing> writings;

    private Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task getWritings()
    {
        string jsonData = await JsonDataManager.GetJsonAsync("1");
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        JArray array = (JArray)obj["posts"];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            Writing writing = new Writing();
            writing.content = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "content");
            writing.date = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "date");
            writing.image = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "url");
            writing.summary = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "excerpt");
            writing.title = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "title");

            writings.Add(writing);
        }

        myLongList.ItemsSource = writings;
    }
}
```

Instead of doing

```
var page = new Page2();
```

you would be using:

```
var page = await Page2.Create();
```

Comment: This approach uses a [factory pattern](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). See another well-received similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12520574/1497596).

Comment: How can I use this with dependency injection (constructor injection)?

Comment: Pass the dependencies through the static create

Comment: Yes, but I need the use this async Create() in the Load() method of my Ninject ApplicationModule. This is because this object is consumed by another object during the injection. There is no way to make an async call in the Application Module.

Comment: I just don't get it no matter how long I stare at this. How does this let you call async code from a constructor?

Comment: It doesn't. It provides an alternate solution to the problem

Comment: I agree with the principles of this solution but I would strongly encourage all who are reading this answer to adopt the common convention of adding `Async` to the end of all methods that contain asynchronous code. e.g. `CreateAsync()`, `InitializeAsync()`. This really helps readers of your code/APIs know which methods need to be awaited.

Comment: @BlairAllen I've never really understood the purpose of that convention. Doesn't the fact that a method return a Task indicate that it can be awaited?

Comment: @Shazi you are absolutely correct. There were days when classes had both Sync and Async methods that do the same thing and to differentiate between them, Microsoft decided to append with Async (see DbContext.SaveChanges... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: @ErikPhilips Ah, that makes sense. Yes if you have both an asynchronous and synchronous version then suffixing the async one with "async" makes sense. So in this case that would actually be redundant information as there is no synchronous method.

Comment: @Shazi I still use it, and Microsoft still recommends it.  It been heavily discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/47592) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod).

Answer (score 16):

A quick way to execute some time-consuming operation in any constructor is by creating an action and run them asynchronously.

```
new Action( async() => await InitializeThingsAsync())();
```

Running this piece of code will neither block your UI nor leave you with any loose threads. And if you need to update any UI (considering you are not using MVVM approach), you can use the Dispatcher to do so as many have suggested.

A Note: This option only provides you a way to start an execution of a method from the constructor if you don't have any `init` or `onload` or `navigated` overrides. Most likely this will keep on running even after the construction has been completed. Hence the result of this method call may **NOT** be available in the constructor itself.

Comment: thanks for your answer can you describe what is different between above solution and Using Task.Run(async () => await InitializeThingsAsync());

Comment: Only difference I can see is you can await the statement `Task.Run(async () => await InitializeThingsAsync());` in an async method. However `new Action( async() => await InitializeThingsAsync())();` is a synchronous call.

Comment: My IDE flags this as having the following problem:
`[VSTHRD101] Avoid using async lambda for a void returning delegate type, because any exceptions not handled by the delegate will crash the process`

Answer (score 10):

My preferred approach:

```
// caution: fire and forget
Task.Run(async () => await someAsyncFunc());
```

Comment: This does not ensure that the data will be available when you'll want to use them, because the `Task` that creates them is fired-and-forgotten. And in case of an exception the data will never become available.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Correct, however the question reads as follows: "I would like to call an asynchronous method in a constructor. Is this possible?" It's possible to perform, but also make sense to know of the pitfalls. Regardless I don't see this exact implementation in any of the other examples on this thread. Also fire-and-forget may be a valid approach depending on scenario, and I'd argue that "data will never become available" could be resolved with exception handling. I've mostly seen this pattern used with MVVM and Desktop/Mobile where you can use two-way data binding to refresh.

Comment: You have a point. Nevertheless, you should at least make it more prominent that you are initiating a fire-and-forget task. Nowadays it seems that the preferred way to do it is to assign it to a discard: `_ = Task.Run(async...`

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias - Thanks for this comment.  My compiler was suggesting I refactor to this discard operator earlier today on something and I had no idea what it was talking about.  Working on something else right now where this helped and all the sudden clicked.  Thanks.

Comment: you can wait it to be done in this way: `var taskVar = Task.Run(async () => await someAsyncFunc()); taskVar.Wait();` it works for me (.net core 3.1)

Comment: That works, but is a bad habit to get into. Eventually you’ll write code that deadlocks. Much better to refactor design so don’t need to wait for result of Async code from a non-async context.

Answer (score 6):

Try to replace this:

```
myLongList.ItemsSource = writings;
```

with this

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => myLongList.ItemsSource = writings);
```

Comment: can you undo your answer cause Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => myLongList.ItemsSource = writings); works finally :) thank you i solve the problem i am gonna select your answer as best

Comment: @KBB check the rollback

Answer (score 4):

To put it simply, referring to Stephen Cleary https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051370/267000

your page on creation should create tasks in constructor and you should declare those tasks as class members or put it in your task pool.

Your data are fetched during these tasks, but these tasks should awaited in the code i.e. on some UI manipulations, i.e. Ok Click etc.

I developped such apps in WP, we had a whole bunch of tasks created on start.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't ever call .Wait() or .Result as this is going to lock your app.
>   Don't spin up a new Task either, just call the ContinueWith

```
public class myClass
{
  public myClass
  {
    GetMessageAsync.ContinueWith(GetResultAsync);
  }

  async Task<string> GetMessageAsync()
  {
    return await Service.GetMessageFromAPI(); 
  }
private async Task GetResultAsync(Task<string> resultTask)
{
    if (resultTask.IsFaulted)
{
      Log(resultTask.Exception); 
}
eles
{
 //do what ever you need from the result
}
}
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/consuming-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern

Answer (score 1):

In order to use async within the constructor and ensure the data is available when you instantiate the class, you can use this simple pattern:

```
class FooClass : IFooAsync
{        
    FooClass 
    {
        this.FooAsync = InitFooTask();
    }

    public Task FooAsync { get; }

    private async Task InitFooTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface IFooAsync
{
    Task FooAsync { get; }
}
```

The usage:

```
FooClass foo = new FooClass();    
if (foo is IFooAsync)
    await foo.FooAsync;
```

Comment: this just shifts awaiting out of the class. The same can be achieved with simple async method. I think the idea was to create "fully automatic slowly instantiated class"

Answer (score 0):

You could try [AsyncMVVM](https://github.com/dmitry-shechtman/AsyncMvvm/).

Page2.xaml:

```
<PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="Page2"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Writings}" />
</PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Page2.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Page2
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel2();
}
```

ViewModel2.cs:

```
public class ViewModel2: AsyncBindableBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Writing> Writings
    {
        get { return Property.Get(GetWritingsAsync); }
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Writing>> GetWritingsAsync()
    {
        string jsonData = await JsonDataManager.GetJsonAsync("1");
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        JArray array = (JArray)obj["posts"];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            Writing writing = new Writing();
            writing.content = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "content");
            writing.date = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "date");
            writing.image = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "url");
            writing.summary = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "excerpt");
            writing.title = JsonDataManager.JsonParse(array, i, "title");
            yield return writing;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A little late to the party, but I think many are struggling with this...**

I've been searching for this as well. And to get your method/action running async without waiting or blocking the thread, you'll need to queue it via the `SynchronizationContext`, so I came up with this solution:

I've made a helper-class for it.

```
public static class ASyncHelper
{

    public static void RunAsync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        // you don't want to run it on a threadpool. So if it is null, 
        // you're not on a UI thread.
        if (context == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "The current thread doesn't have a SynchronizationContext");

        // post an Action as async and await the function in it.
        context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(async state => await func()), null);
    }

    public static void RunAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> func, T argument)
    {
        var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        // you don't want to run it on a threadpool. So if it is null, 
        // you're not on a UI thread.
        if (context == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "The current thread doesn't have a SynchronizationContext");

        // post an Action as async and await the function in it.
        context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(async state => await func((T)state)), argument);
    }
}
```

---

Usage/Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        // replace code here...
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    private async Task Run(string myString)
    {

        // replace code here...
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // you don't have to await nothing.. (the thread must be running)
        ASyncHelper.RunAsync(Initialize);
        ASyncHelper.RunAsync(Run, "test");

        // In your case
        ASyncHelper.RunAsync(getWritings);
    }
}
```

**This works for Windows.Forms and WPF**

Answer (score 0):

Brian Lagunas has shown a solution that I really like. More info [his youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1Tx-k4Vao0)

Solution:

Add a TaskExtensions method

```
  public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async void Await(this Task task, Action completedCallback = null ,Action<Exception> errorCallBack = null )
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
            completedCallback?.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorCallBack?.Invoke(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
  public class MyClass
{

    public MyClass()
    {
        DoSomething().Await();
       // DoSomething().Await(Completed, HandleError);
    }

    async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        //Some works here
        //throw new Exception("Thrown in task");
    }

    private void Completed()
    {
        //some thing;
    }

    private void HandleError(Exception ex)
    {
        //handle error
    }

}
```

Comment: async void methods are only allowed for EventHandlers. Await() with no parameters won't wait, but will do something called fire and forget, where you just start the async process and don't wait for it. At least await task.ConfigureAwait(false) should be called to have save calls in different SynchronisationContexts.

Comment: Well, I thought this was the best hope for me.  I'll just have to whimp out.  I simply cannot make an async EF Add/Insert from my constuctor in a base controller class.  To many hours and days and days and hours at this point.  Have to bail and make it synchronous.

Comment: Actually I am still getting my error but I am using this structure.  I think it is helpful to see what is going on.  The exception handler is catching my error.

Comment: @Sam Make the constructor private. Then create a public static async Task<YourTypeHere> Create() method.

Answer (score -1):

An alrernative would be to do what Microsoft recommend the following at
[JoinableTaskFactory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/asynchronous-and-multithreaded-programming-within-vs-using-the-joinabletaskfactory/) site

```cs
public Page2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.Run(async delegate 
    {
        await getWritings();
    });
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could put the async calls in a separate method and call that method in the constructor.
Although, this may lead to a situation where some variable values not being available at the time you expect them.

```
 public NewTravelPageVM(){
   GetVenues();              
 }

 async void  GetVenues(){
   var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
   var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync();
   Venues = await Venue.GetVenues(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

The answer is simple, If you are developing an UWP app, then add the async function to the `Page_Loaded` method of the page.