# How to handle asynchronous method call in constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, constructor, async-await

I've added a call to an asynchronous method in my constructor, in order to initialize data for the ViewModel when loaded.

But I noticed there is a warning on the calling of that method in the VM constructor. It states that `"this call is not awaited"`

I understand from this error that the call needs to be prefixed with `await`. but this would also mean that the constructor would have to be marked as an `async Task` which I know it can't be in C#. As constructors can't be async.

I did come across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048285/how-to-call-async-method-in-constructor) here, but some practical code examples related to my implementation that uses dependency injection, would be a help.

Does anyone have an example, of how to refactor the call out of the constructor?
Or what implementation pattern to use instead?

This is a summarized version of the ViewModel, showing how I call the method in the constructor:

```
namespace MongoDBApp.ViewModels
{

    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class CustomerDetailsViewModel 
    {

        private IDataService<CustomerModel> _customerDataService;
        private IDataService<Country> _countryDataService;

        public CustomerDetailsViewModel(IDataService<CustomerModel> customerDataService, IDataService<Country> countryDataService) 
        {
            this._customerDataService = customerDataService;
            this._countryDataService = countryDataService;

            //warning about awaiting call, shown here...
            GetAllCustomersAsync();

        }


      #region Properties


        public ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }


      #endregion


        #region methods


        private async Task GetAllCustomersAsync()
        {
            var customerResult = await _customerDataService.GetAllAsync();
            Customers = customerResult.ToObservableCollection();

            var countryResult = await _countryDataService.GetAllAsync();
            Countries = countryResult.ToObservableCollection();
        }



        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you should move your async call into the properties themselves and lazy load them there.

Comment: ok could you provide an example of how to implement that?

Comment: You want something like http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html

Comment: I ended up using the "The Asynchronous Initialization Pattern" example from the below link. As the first factory example doesn't seem to work with my DI ctor. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html