# Async method doesn't get executed even when it gets called

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

My workflow: Constructor -> Calls async Method 1 -> Calls async Method 2 -> Calls async Method 3

Constructor:

```
public MyConstructor() {
    Method1();
}
```

Method1:

```
private async void Method1() {
    //do some stuff
    await Method2();
    //do some more stuff
}
```

Method 2:

```
protected internal async Task Method2() {
    //do some stuff
    var x = await Method3("someParams");
    //do some more stuff
}
```

Method 3:

```
public async Task<List<string>> Method3(string someParams) {
    Debug.WriteLine("I am here"); //Breakpoint doesn't get hit, no output "I am here"
}
```

Yeah I know, you probably wonder why I am using so many different async methods.. But there is some more stuff going on (but nothing that influences the problem!). The problem is, `Debug.WriteLine("I am here");` does **not** get hit, and no exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't get hit as in you've put a breakpoint and it's not hit, or not hit as you don't see output from `Debug.WriteLine`?

Comment: Both.. Breakpoint does not get hitted, and I also dont see any output..

Comment: Tested this code and its working for me, probably your problem somewhere else

Comment: You are not awaiting your call of `Method1`, so maybe the execution stops before `Method3` gets called.

Comment: Do you see `Method1` and `Method2` get hit?

Comment: @fknx Makes a good point. If this is a console app or there's no other thread running, it's possible that the app terminates before it can get to `Method3`

Comment: @fknx yeah, maybe.. But I cant use async await in a constructor.. 
Brandon: yeah, I also added a breakpoint in Method2 (var x = await...) and it it gets executed. But the things below var x = await Method3(...) don't get executed

Comment: True, you can't use `async await` in the constructor. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048285/call-asynchronous-method-in-constructor) for possible workarounds. It links to this [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) which introduces a factory pattern that might be useful.

Comment: @Fabio any idea how to debug this?

Comment: @hansmeyer: Every `async` method *begins* executing synchronously. The code you posted does not have any actual asynchronous work, so it will always synchronously print the debug line. Try to develop a minimal, complete, reproducible example and then post it (as it currently stands, the problem is not reproducible).

Comment: You declare Method 3 async, so I assume there is an await above the Debug.WriteLine() that you are not showing.  In which case - as Stephen says - all the initial sync parts of all your methods are executing, but on the await I refer to execution returns all the way back up to your constructor, which exits.  The Debug.WriteLine() will eventually execute, but I'm guessing that in the scope you're in (perhaps a unit-test or console app that exits at that point), it is not seen.

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell: yes, as @fknx mentioned in a comment, the problem is that the code executes asynchronously and is not awaited, therefore the app exits before reaching the line in question.

There are a couple of bad practices in your example:

#### async void method

It is not a good idea to create such things as you loose track of the task. Please always define *Task* as the return value, it does not cost anything and it will help you write a correct API.

#### asynchronous call in a constructor

This is not a good design either, because (as you mentioned) you cannot await this method in a constructor so you will just fire up the task and loose it. Please consider using an async *Init* method instead.

So instead of this:

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
    public MyCustomClass()
    {
        // BAD CODE, do not do this
        Method1();
    }

    private async Task Method1()
    {
        //do some stuff
        await Method2();
        //do some more stuff
    }
}
```

You could do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new MyCustomClass();

        m.InitializeAsync().Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("Before exit...");
    }
}

public class MyCustomClass
{
    public MyCustomClass()
    {
        // in a constructor you should not do anything async
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await Method1();
    }

    private async Task Method1()
    {
        //do some stuff
        await Method2();
        //do some more stuff
    }
}
```

It is absolutely **OK to Wait for an async method in the Main method**, or to be precise your console app should have **only one Wait** (or WaitAll, or whatever) method in the main method (and nowhere else) if you want to create a truly async app.