# why do I have this Rest Api uri error?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq2fz.png)

I have my Universal Windows Application and i want work with rest api. 
I always get error CS 4032 in this  :

```
httpResponseBody = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
```

Like you can't call that method when it is not async.

Whole code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Net;
using Windows.Web.Http;
namespace UniversalCA
{

   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Send();             

        }

        public string Send()
        { 
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://restapic.azurewebsites.net/WebForm1.aspx?func=dd&hodn=WW");
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
            string httpResponseBody = "";
            try
            {
                httpResponseBody = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            string tt = httpResponseBody.Split('>')[1].Split('<')[0];
            return httpResponseBody;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable for others

Comment: Why do you have this line: `HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();`? You don't seem to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot use `await` keyword inside a not `async` function. Your `Send` function does not have `async` keyword in declaration. Adding `async` keyword will solve the problem

```
public async Task<string> Send()
```

Comment: That will never compile, async methods must return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`

Answer (score 0):

Just To add to @Ruben Vardanyans answer.

simply:
add `using System.Threading.Tasks;`

add `Wait()` keyword on your Send(); call

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Send().Wait();             

    }
```

and finally on your Send() method 
add `async Task<T>`

```
  public async Task<string> Send()
```

Please check out this answer for calling an asynchronous method inside a constructor. [Call asynchronous method in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048285/call-asynchronous-method-in-constructor)

do not use `await Send();` for calling the method you will have a compiler error.