# Work done off main thread to keep UI active

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await, task

I want to do some work with a coded in Delay with the UI active.

I thought I had `TaskOfTResult_MethodSync` fixed with `Task.Delay(delay).Wait();`. The problem is that blocks `Task<int> taskS = TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(10000);` it does not immediately move on to the `await` and the UI is not responsive.  UI does not even paint until after the delay.

`public async void TestTask3(int delay, CancellationToken ct)` works but it does not let me return a value.

If I use

```
int rslt = TestTask3(1000, token).Result;
public async Task<int> TestTask3(int delay, CancellationToken ct)
```

It hangs on `int rslt = TestTask3(1000, token).Result;`

This is not valid syntax `await TestTask3(1000, token);`

I don't mind using `public async void TestTask3(int delay, CancellationToken ct)` but I would rather have work done with programmed Delay or Sleep that returns a value (rather than update a public property from the async method). What I want is to kick off a method / task then do some other work from the main tread. Then `await`.  After the `await` some buttons get activated.

The reason I need a programmed in delay is it reads some instrument data and it needs to wait between reads to get a sample set.

Is there a way to get what I want?

I currently get what I need with BackGroundWorker but that but I was hoping to get there with task.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();

    Debug.WriteLine("before Task<int> taskS = TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(10000);");
    Task<int> taskS = TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(10000);
    Debug.WriteLine("before taskS.Wait");
    taskS.Wait();
    Debug.WriteLine("after  taskS.Wait");
    int i = taskS.Result;
    Debug.WriteLine($"i = {i}");
    Debug.WriteLine($"");

    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = source.Token;
    Debug.WriteLine("before TestTask3(1000, token);");
    TestTask3(1000, token);
    Debug.WriteLine("after TestTask3(1000, token);");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Debug.WriteLine("after sleep on main TestTask3(1000, token);");
    source.Cancel();

    Debug.WriteLine("done Main");
}

public async void TestTask3(int delay, CancellationToken ct)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"TestTask3");
    int ans = -1;
    ans = await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // … do compute-bound work here 
        for (int j = 101; j <= 120; j++)
        {
            if(ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            ans = j;
            Answer = j;
        }
    });
    Debug.WriteLine($"TestTask3   {ans}");
    Answer = ans;
    //return ans;
}        
Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(int delay)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"TaskOfTResult_MethodSync delay = {delay}  {DateTime.Now}");
    int hours = 10; 
    Task.Delay(delay).Wait();
    Debug.WriteLine($"TaskOfTResult_MethodSync after delay   {DateTime.Now}");
    return Task.FromResult(hours);
}
```

Comment: Both .Wait() and .Result block.

Comment: @mm8 Yes.  .Result not only blocks it hangs - does not move on and no error.

Comment: I ran your code and it doesn't hang for me. (I did have to add an `Answer` property and remove the `ans =` from in front of the `await Task.Run`). It does block for the expected 12 seconds (10 + 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do here but both `Wait()` and `Result` will block synchronously.

You should make the `TaskOfTResult_MethodSync` method `async` and await `Task.Delay`:

```
async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(int delay)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"TaskOfTResult_MethodSync delay = {delay}  {DateTime.Now}");
    int hours = 10;
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    Debug.WriteLine($"TaskOfTResult_MethodSync after delay   {DateTime.Now}");
    return hours;
}
```

This makes the method asynchronous method.

Since the constructor is not asynchronous you could then move the invocation of the asynchronous method to a `Loaded` event handler. And `TestTask3` should not return `void` if you want to be able to await it. Change the return type to `Task` and await this one also.

Finally, if call `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread, your UI will indeed freeze. Use `await Task.Delay` if you want to "sleep" asynchronously:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += async (s, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("before Task<int> taskS = TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(10000);");
        int i = await TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(10000);
        Debug.WriteLine($"i = {i}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"");

        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        Debug.WriteLine("before TestTask3(1000, token);");
        await TestTask3(1000, token);
        Debug.WriteLine("after TestTask3(1000, token);");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Debug.WriteLine("after sleep on main TestTask3(1000, token);");
        source.Cancel();

        Debug.WriteLine("done Main");
    };
}

public async Task TestTask3(int delay, CancellationToken ct)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"TestTask3");
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // … do compute-bound work here 
        for (int j = 101; j <= 120; j++)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            ans = j;
            Answer = j;
        }
    });
    Debug.WriteLine($"TestTask3   {ans}");
    Answer = ans;
}
```

Comment: That sleep on the main was just to test the source.Cancel();.  I should have taken it out.

Comment: Well, what about the rest?

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on `ans = await Task.Run(async () =>` or cannot convert type void to int.

Comment: @paparazzo the lambda expression doesn't return a value so there isn't anything to be assigned to `ans`. You are assigning the value in the lambda so you don't need to assign a result. You can just `await` the `Task.Run`.

Comment: @AdamKingsley Yes I just figured that out.  Removing ans = fixed the syntax error.

Comment: It is running but there is a UI delay somewhere.

Comment: @paparazzo the delays I had were 10 seconds from the `TaskS` then 2 seconds from `Thread.Sleep(2000)` then 1 second from the `delay` in `TestTask3`

Comment: Yes, the and variable is superfluous. I removed it.  You are supposed to get asynchronous delays.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first issues that I noted in your code is that you are making all this async calls in your constructor (that's why you can't `await TestTask3`). I suggest you [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048285/call-asynchronous-method-in-constructor) to understand why this is bad.

Now, if you move your code to not be in your constructor, then you don't need to use the blocking constructs (like `Wait()` and `.Result`) and use `await` instead. For example, here is what `TaskOfTResult_MethofSync` implementation could look like:

```
private async Task<int> TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(int delay)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);
    return Task.FromResult(10);
}
```

Note how instead of blocking on the `.Delay` call it now *awaits*

Comment: Yes that worked.  What I cannot figure out is how to get in information back.  `int i = await TaskOfTResult_MethodSync(10000);` just stalls (never finishes);