# c# Task.WhenAll to block while awaiting completion

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

I have a simple Winforms application. I would like to background TCP connections/print requests and check the output of all tasks at a set point in my code.

I would expect `ReportOnTasks` to block until `WaitAll` is complete. Please could someone explain why this is not the case? I'm also worried I haven't structured this correctly.

Edit, to clarify my intentions:
I would like to send the print jobs as soon as I receive the data. Then continue with some other DB operations. Once all the print operations are complete, I would like to update the UI to state the result.

I've attempted to simplify the code as much as I can. Maybe too much. HomeController just inits some stuff. There are buttons on the form and file watchers that trigger the main functionality.

```
public class HomeController 
{

    public HomeController(){

        MessageBox.Show("1");

        oPrintController.PrintAsync("192.168.2.213", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("string to print"));

        MessageBox.Show("2");

        // Block here untill tasks are complete
        ReportOnTasks();

        MessageBox.Show("Report on tasks complete");
    }


    public async void ReportOnTasks()
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(oPrintController.Tasks);

        foreach(Task<PrintController.PrintResult> PR in oPrintController.Tasks)
        {
            // do something with the result of task
        }
    }
}
```

and the `PrintController`

```
public class PrintController
{

    public List<Task<PrintResult>> Tasks = new List<Task<PrintResult>>();


    public async void PrintAsync(string sIP, List<byte[]> lsToPrint, int iPort = 9100)
    {
        var s = await Task.Run(() => PrintAsync1(sIP, lsToPrint));
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<PrintResult> PrintAsync1(string sIP, List<byte[]> lsToPrint, int iPort = 9100)
    {

        using (TcpClient tc = new TcpClient())
        {
            await tc.ConnectAsync(sIP, iPort);
            using (var ns = tc.GetStream())
            {
                foreach (byte[] btLabel in lsToPrint)
                {
                    await ns.WriteAsync(btLabel, 0, btLabel.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        return new PrintResult();
    }
}

public class PrintResult
{
    bool bSuccess = false;
}
```

Comment: The problem is, is that you're trying to call an async method from your constructor, which isn't/cannot be async. You should check this question: [Call asynchronous method in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048285/call-asynchronous-method-in-constructor)

Comment: I would create an `public async Task Initialize() { }` method to initialize the class.

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by block? Do you mean "block UI"? If so, then no, point of async/await is to *not* block. However, if you mean, not continue executing until ... and then not completing its task until ... then yes, that should happen.

Comment: However, ReportOnTasks is a method returning a Task, you're not awaiting this task, so essentially you're kicking off this task in a fire-and-forget manner.

Comment: I would like to send the print jobs as soon as I receive the data. Then continue with some other DB operations. Once all the print operations are complete, I would like to update the UI to state such. @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I would like to wait until tasks are complete then do somthing

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Have resolved the issue by refactoring using whats been so kindly explained here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not `await`ing the call to `ReportOnTasks()`
Moreover, you can't `await` within a ctor, because they can't be async.

Depending on how your `HomeController` is used, you could use a static async method which returns an instance of `HomeController`, created by a private ctor instead:

Something like this:

```
public class HomeController 
{

    //notice private - you can't new up a HomeController - you have to use `CreateInstance`
    private HomeController(){

        MessageBox.Show("1");

        //not clear from your code where oPrintController comes from??
        oPrintController.PrintAsync("192.168.2.213", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("string to print"));

        MessageBox.Show("2");

        MessageBox.Show("Report on tasks complete");
    }

    public static async Task<HomeController> CreateInstance() {
        var homeController = new HomeController();

        await homeController.ReportOnTasks();

        return homeController;
    }


    //don't use async void! Change to Task
    public async Task ReportOnTasks()
    {
        //not clear from your code where oPrintController comes from??
        await Task.WhenAll(oPrintController.Tasks);

        foreach(Task<PrintController.PrintResult> PR in oPrintController.Tasks)
        {
            // do something with the result of task
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var homeControllerInstance = await HomeController.CreateInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for this Alex. In Main.cs I have a `MainForm()` method which inits `HomeController`. HomeController then inits the PrintController in its constructor. Am attempting to implement this now

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not recommended to perform heavy operations in class constructors, but I suppose you won't change that part, so in order to wait for `ReportOnTasks` to finish, you need to make it synchronous.

Take into account, that constructor itself doesn't support async/await, it's not possible to mark it `async`.

Having said that, you won't have real performance enhancement marking `void ReportOnTasks` as `async`. In addition, it is not recommended to mark `void` methods as `async` due to issues with exceptions handling, which is usually not possible.

So, you can either postpone `ReportOnTasks` like Alex showed you, or you can synchronously wait until all tasks are finished (which is possible inside ctor).

```
    public void ReportOnTasks()
    {
        Task.WhenAll(oPrintController.Tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); //synchronously wait

        foreach(Task<PrintController.PrintResult> PR in oPrintController.Tasks)
        {
            // do something with the result of task
        }
    }
```

However, I wouldn't suggest this approach, because instance creation will take a while and most importantly block UI thread - and that's usually signal something is really fishy

Comment: If you call `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the UI thread, it can cause a deadlock, which is what the OP is trying to avoid http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Thanks this code is simplified. There are no big calls in the constructor

Comment: @Alex I'm aware of that, but since question asks to block inside ctor, it's obvious that thread which instantiates HomeController will be blocked? In addition, I enlisted why that is not ok to do...