# How to use asynchronous method in constructor when .Result() makes the method hang?

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

I have an AppearingCommand called when a Page appears in my Xamarin.Forms project, that eventually executes the following sqlite-net-pcl line: (I already have a mechanism coping with loading time)

```
AppearingCommand = new Command( async() => {
    //...
    var data = await db.Table<PlantCategory>().ToListAsync();
    //...
}
```

I want to move this method to the constructor, but I cannot do it, as it hangs if it is executed synchronously:

```
ctor() {
    //...
    var data = db.Table<PlantCategory>().ToListAsync().Result;
    //...
}
```

The line never returns (I am guessing because of a deadlock or something).
What are other options that I have if I want to execute this line inside the constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call asynchronous method in constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048285/call-asynchronous-method-in-constructor)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I already have a mechanism to cope with loading time. It is irrelevant for the question. I know it is possible, that's not my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple. Don't.

Instead, add a post-construction method like `async ValueTask InitAsync()` and call that with `await`.

You could hide this behind a `static ValueTask<Whatever> CreateAsync(...)` method that you call *instead of* `new Whatever(...)`, i.e.

```cs
class Whatever {
    private Whatever(...) { ... } // basic ctor
    private async ValueTask InitAsync(...) { ... } // async part of ctor

    public static async ValueTask<Whatever> CreateAsync(...) {
        var obj = new Whatever(...);
        await obj.InitAsync(...);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: As this is Xamarin.Forms, it uses .NET Standard. No `ValueTask` there pre-2.1.

Comment: @iSpain17 `ValueTask[<T>]` goes down to .NET Standard 1.0 and .NET 4.5 https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/4.5.3

Comment: Cool, thanks! I managed to refactor like this, so I'll accept as answer.