# Async Binding Issues with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind data to a grid using MVVM Light. If I do the following it works:

```
public class GuidePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<SimpleChannelData> _simpleChannelDataList;
    private IChannelDataService _channelDataService;

    public GuidePageViewModel(IChannelDataService channelDataService)
    {
        _channelDataService = channelDataService;

        ATest(); // Create data synchronously here
    }

    private void ATest()
    {
        SimpleChannelDataList = new ObservableCollection<SimpleChannelData>();

        var record = new SimpleChannelData()
        {
            Cn = 120,
            Csign = "Hey",
            Hd = "Y",
            Index = 1,
            Premium = "y",
            TrbId = 9
        };

        SimpleChannelDataList.Add(record);
    }

    private async void Start()
    {
        await LoadChannelData();
    }

    private async Task LoadChannelData()
    {
        SimpleChannelDataList = new ObservableCollection<SimpleChannelData>((await _channelDataService.GetChannelData()));
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SimpleChannelDataList);
    }

    #region Public Properties

    public ObservableCollection<SimpleChannelData> SimpleChannelDataList
    {
        get
        {
            return _simpleChannelDataList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Set(() => SimpleChannelDataList, ref  _simpleChannelDataList, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SimpleChannelDataList);
            }

        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now, if I change the constructor to the following instead, using an asynchronous call to `Start`, the grid does not get the data:

```
public GuidePageViewModel(IChannelDataService channelDataService)
{
    _channelDataService = channelDataService;
    Start();
}
```

I know this some sort of Async issue, but I cannot figure it out. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Calling an `async void` method from synchronous methods should work fine (although being dangerous). Can you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should not call async methods in the [constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356810/async-binding-issues-with-mvvm-light). Try to change your logic so that that call is not required.

In mean time, try to check [AsyncMVVM](https://github.com/dmitry-shechtman/AsyncMvvm/). It contains some interesting patterns to retrieve in an async way the data while exposing the usual MVVM interface.

Comment: Why the link to this very question? I was expecting some information on why not to call async void methods in a constructor. And this does not really answer the question.

Comment: I gave you informations on that. Check the link on the "Constructor" word :)

Comment: As I said, that link leads to *this* question.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async)

Comment: Okay, that link is better. However, it still doesn’t explain why you “should not call async methods in the constructor”. It only explains why it’s not possible for a constructor to be asynchronous. But it even explicitly mentions the fire-and-forget idea of calling an `async void` method from within the constructor. Because calling an `async void` method is a good way to start an asynchronous process from within any synchronous method—including constructors. OP’s code is fine and should be working; and this still does not answer the question (which I’d say is currently impossible to answer).

Comment: The first answer provides a more-or-less clear explanation on that.
About your issue, I'll be more than happy to provide a full example as soon as possible.