# Injecting IDbConnection vs IDbConnectionFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, dapper

**TLDR:** What are the reasons for injecting a connection factory vs the IDbConnection itself.

I'm currently using Autofac in .net MVC to inject an instance of IDbConnection into my repository classes to use with Dapper like so:

**Autofac setup:**

```
builder.Register<IDbConnection>(ctx => new
    SqlConnection(conSettings.ConnectionString)).InstancePerRequest();
```

**Repo:**

```
public ClientRepository(IDbConnection connection)
{
    _connection = connection;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Client>> GetAsync()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
    return (await _connection.QueryAsync<Client>(query)).ToList();
}
```

This has been working perfectly fine for me so far, but I'm a little worried about connections staying open and not being disposed of.

Every post I find on the topic ends in someone suggesting passing in a connection factory and calling it in a using statement, without really mentioning why my current setup is "bad".

As far as I can tell every request should get it's own IDbConnection where Dapper takes care of opening and closing the connection and Autofac takes care of the disposing.

Is this not the case? Am I missing something?

Comment: Make your repository IDisposable, then close the connection (if open) in the dispose method.

Answer (score 3):

They way I'm doing this on an ASP.NET Core project (bear with me for a second, I know it's not what you're using but the concept still applies) is injecting the connection string through the repository constructor.

*As you will see, I actually inject the `IConfiguration` object because I need other settings from the configuration file because of other requirements. Just pretend it's the connection string.*

Then my repository looks like this (rough example, written off the top of my head so forgive any mistakes I might have made):

```
public class FooRepository
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public FooRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration
    }

    private IDbConnection Connection => new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnectionString"));

    public Foo GetById(int id)
    {
        using (var connection = Connection)
        {
            return connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<Foo>("select * from ...", new {id});
        }
    }
}
```

ADO.NET connections are pooled, opening one as needed and then closing it is the way it's usually done. With `using` you make sure the connections gets closed and disposed - returned to the pool - as soon as you're done, even if an exception gets thrown.

Of course you might want to extract this common code to an abstract superclass, so that you won't need to repeat the name of the connection string in every repository, nor re-implement the `Connection` property.

<s>Also, as I mentioned in my comment, Dapper is not in charge of opening or closing connections, in fact it fully expects the connection to be open before you can call any of its methods.</s> **This is no longer true, sorry**.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Your comment on dapper expecting an open connection is outdated information and as stated on the dapper forums "Dapper now (and for quite some time) deals with this internally. It just works". Also none of the examples in the dapper documentation open the connection before use.

Comment: @GisleK thanks, I was not aware that things have changed. I edited my answer and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you only inject IDbConnection, that means your repository can only use that one connection and you are relying on the IoC to close/dispose of that connection for you.  Also, if you need to connect to two different databases, you can't since you only allow one connection to be created here.  If you want to run queries in parallel, you can't since you can only have one open call to a single database at a time.  Finally, if getting your connection string is a bit harder and isn't straight from a config file (like a KeyVault), then you need to call an outside Async method or something that IoC won't let you do probably.

For me, I always use a factory because I want to close any connection as soon as I'm done with it instead of waiting for IoC to get rid of it. (It feels dirty to allow something outside of the repository to manage database connections.)  I want control over which database I'm connecting to (I often have more than 1 DB I have to work with).  I occasionally need to run a bunch of different queries in parallel in order to return all the data I need, so I need multiple connections in a single method.  I also have to do some logic since we store our connection strings in Azure Key Vault, so I have to do an async call to get that with secret information, which gets a bit complicated, so the Create method on the factory ends up doing a lot of work.

Comment: To play devil's advocate on some points: 1) If you had databases `Foo` and `Bar`, you could inject `IFooConnection` and `IBarConnection`, just as you might inject `IFooConnectionFactory` and `IBarConnectionFactory` instead of `IConnectionFactory`.  2) It's not dirty to let DI manage lifetimes and dispose of `IDisposable`s.  That's one of its core responsibilities.  3) If you needed parallel connections to a single database, you could use a *transient* DI lifetime instead of a *scoped* lifetime so each `IFooConnection` injection request would be given a different connection.

Comment: 4) I also just stumbled on [this fascinating solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240576/5405967) that uses a lazy wrapper to allow a dependency whose creation is slow/async to still be resolved by a DI container.

Comment: I don't think it's the DI's responsibility to determine when to close the connection.  When you work with Files, do you let the DI determine when the connection to the file is closed?  It would end up locking that file indefinitely if it was configured to be a singleton.  Any time I have IO, I want to get my stuff and immediately close it so there isn't any contention.

Comment: 1) I won't argue for using DI with the wrong lifetime (singleton).  If it's a short-lived web request and you choose the right lifetime, the delay in releasing the connection to the pool will be negligible compared to disposing of it manually.  2) Regarding files and the responsibility of DI, I haven't used a DI *container* to open/close a file, but it's common to open a file, inject the stream into a consumer for processing, and then close the file: `using FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path); return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream);`

Comment: If you inject an EF instance, for example, you cannot run that multi-threaded.  You need to create a new EF instance to be able to run both concurrently.  That is why I want to just inject the connection factory.  Most queries won't be multi-threaded, but some will and I want to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I agree completely that the advice out there seems to be consistently in favor of injecting factories over injecting connections and that it's hard to find much discussion of why.

I think it's fine in straightforward cases to have your container inject the connection itself, which is simple and immediately alleviates 100% of this repetitive boilerplate: `using var conn = _connFactory.Make()`.

But the advantage of having the container inject a factory instead is that it gives you more control over connection creation/lifetime.  One common situation where this control really matters is when you want to use `TransactionScope`.  Since it must be instantiated *before* any connections that you want to participate in the transaction, it doesn't make sense to use a DI container to create connections ahead of time.  Daniel Lorenz brought up a couple of other situations where you might want fine control over connection creation in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060012/5405967).

If you decided to go the opposite direction (usually not recommended) by using `DbConnection.BeginTransaction` to manage transactions rather than `TransactionScope`, then you'd need to share your `DbConnection`/`DbTransaction` instances among all the queries/methods/classes involved in the transaction.  In that case, injecting connection factories everywhere and letting classes do their own thing would no longer work.  A reasonable solution would be to inject either a connection or a connection factory (doesn't really matter which) into a Unit-of-Work type of class and then inject that into your classes with the actual queries in them (Repositories or whatever).  If you want to go deep into the weeds on this topic, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298235/how-to-implement-unit-of-work-pattern-with-dapper).