# Dependency injection class that is resolved by async provider

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have an api client that in its constructor accepts access token

```
public class ApiClient : IApiClient
{
    public ApiClient(string accessToken)
}
```

To get that api token I need to create instance of another class and call method GetTokenAsync()

```
public class TokenClient
{
     public Task<string> GetTokenAsync();
}
```

now I want to inject `IApiClient` to my `TestService`

```
public class TestService
{
   public TestService(IApiClient client)
}
```

However it is not possible register instance in this way

```
services.AddScoped<IApiClient,ApiClient>(async x=> 
{
  tokenClient = x.GetService<TokenClient>();
  var token = await tokenClient.GetTokenAsync();
  return new ApiClient(token);
}
```

to overcome that I have created `ApiClientProvider` class

```
public class ApiClientProvider()
{
  public async Task<IApiClient> GetClientAsync()
  {
    tokenClient = x.GetService<TokenClient>();
      var token = await tokenClient.GetTokenAsync();
      return new ApiClient(token);
  }
}
```

and now I inject it to `TestService`
but in every method I have to use

```
IApiClient apiClient= await _apiClientProvider.GetClientAsync();
```

I don not like this code, I prefer when dependencies are injected and not resolved in every function, however I do not see any way around. Can you advise if this can be moved to registration or maybe it shouldn't go there.

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240576/7718439

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your design slightly.

Rather than inject a string into your `ApiClient`, inject an `ITokenClient`:

```
public interface ITokenClient
{
    Task<string> GetTokenAsync();
}

public class TokenClient : ITokenClient
{
     public Task<string> GetTokenAsync() { }
}

public class ApiClient : IApiClient
{
    readonly Task<string> tokenTask;

    public ApiClient(ITokenClient tokenClient)
    {
        // Initiate the token request on construction
        tokenTask = tokenClient.GetTokenAsync();
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        string token = await tokenTask;
        // Use your token..
    }
}
```

Any methods that rely on the token must be `async`, but as your calling an API they're likely to be `async` anyway.

Using this method, you simply need to register your clients with the container and no factories / provider types are required.