# Async provider in .NET Core DI properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Regarding to this topic and answer I have adapters for my async services registrations :
[Async provider in .NET Core DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240405/async-provider-in-net-core-di)

And it looks very fine. But I have some services, where I have properties in interface. Properties cant be async, but I need to await client object : `var client = await this.connectedClient.Value;`

I mean I cant use `public bool Connected => (await this.connectedClient.Value).Connected;`

What should I do in this case?

```
public interface IMyAppService
{
    bool Connected{ get; }
    string Host{ get; }
    Task<Data> GetData();
    Task SendData(Data data);
}
```

PS : I dont want to `.Result` and `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` etc. I know Its potentially deadlock there

Answer (score 0):

Given the adapter structure suggested by Steven in the linked question, you can simply implement the `Connected` property as:

```
public bool Connected => this.connectedClient.IsValueCreated;
```

but in the general case, there is no way to run code asynchronously in a property getter or setter.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatelly, Connected not related to connectedClient. Its related to another internal client. And also I have many properties in class, here two is just for example.