# DI repository which depends on factory with an asynchronous resolve method

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, adapter

I have a `UserRepository` which depends on `IDynamoDbClientFactory`. The problem is that `IDynamoDbClientFactory` has one method and it is asynchronous. The ServiceCollections DI framework doesn't allow me to have an async provider. I'm not allowed to change `DynamoDbClientFactory` as it's in an external library.

How do I deal with that in better way than what I did below using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IDynamoDbClientFactory, DynamoDbClientFactory>();

services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository>(provider =>
{
    var dbClientFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IDynamoDbClientFactory>();
    var dynamoDb = dbClientFactory.GetClientAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return new UserRepository(dynamoDb);
});
```

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240405/async-provider-in-net-core-di) which suggests using an adapter in order to hide the async operation from the application code.

I removed the not important code for the sake of simplicity.

```cs
public interface IDynamoDbClientFactory
{
    Task<IAmazonDynamoDB> GetClientAsync();
}

public sealed class DynamoDbClientFactory : IDynamoDbClientFactory
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private IAmazonDynamoDB? _client;
    private DateTime _clientTimeout;

    public DynamoDbClientFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _clientTimeout = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public async Task<IAmazonDynamoDB> GetClientAsync()
    {
        var cutoff = _clientTimeout - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        if (_client != null && cutoff > DateTime.Now)
        {
            return _client;
        }

        var assumeRoleArn = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AWS:AssumeRole");

        if (assumeRoleArn == null)
        {
            _client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
            _clientTimeout = DateTime.MaxValue;
        }
        else
        {
            var credentials = await GetCredentials(assumeRoleArn);
            _client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
            _clientTimeout = credentials!.Expiration;
        }

        return _client;
    }

    private async Task<Credentials?> GetCredentials(string roleArn)
    {
        using var client = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient();
        var response = await client.AssumeRoleAsync(new AssumeRoleRequest
        {
            RoleArn = roleArn,
            RoleSessionName = "configManagerApi",
        });

        if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return response.Credentials;
        }

        throw new ApplicationException($"Could not assume role {roleArn}");
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IAmazonDynamoDB _dynamoDb;

    public UserRepository(IAmazonDynamoDB dynamoDb)
    {
        _dynamoDb = dynamoDb;
    }

    public async Task<UserDto?> GetAsync(string hashKey, string sortKey)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(UserDto userDto)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(UserDto userDto)
    {
        ...
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string hashKey, string sortKey)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The following is unused.

```cs
// The adapter hides the details about GetClientAsync from the application code.
// It wraps the creation and connection of `MyClient` in a `Lazy<T>`,
// which allows the client to be connected just once, independently of in which order the `GetClientAsync`
// method is called, and how many times.
public class DynamoDbClientAdapter : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IDynamoDbClientFactory>> _factories;

    public DynamoDbClientAdapter(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _factories = new Lazy<Task<IDynamoDbClientFactory>>(async () =>
        {
            var client = new DynamoDbClientFactory(configuration);
            await client.GetClientAsync();
            return client;
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_factories.IsValueCreated)
        {
            _factories.Value.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The repo pattern is useful when it _removes duplicated ORM search code_ (e.g. `GetAllSeniorsWithCovid()`) from the codebase not act as a simple CRUD interface, otherwise it could write a single CRUD repo generic handling all types.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more code? Why is `GetClientAsync` async?

Comment: Can't you pass a Task into your UserTradeRepository constructor?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, edited the question with that code.

Comment: Why doesn't the similar question you linked to provide you with an answer? It's unclear to me what you're still missing.

Comment: @Steven, I don't know how to wrap things up.

Comment: If there some scenario where you have something to await in your `GetClientAsync` method, because at the moment it's running 100% synchronously, and needn't return a `Task` or be `async`.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama, I'm not allowed to change that method. It should remain like that. (it's an external library).

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That's annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IDynamoDbClientFactory, DynamoDbClientFactory>();
services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, DynamicClientUserRepositoryAdapter>();
```

Where `DynamicClientUserRepositoryAdapter` is an adapter inside your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) that creates the real `UserRepository` lazily on demand based on its required `IAmazonDynamoDB`:

```cs
public class DynamicClientUserRepositoryAdapter : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IDynamoDbClientFactory factory;
    private IUserRepository repository;

    public DynamicClientUserRepositoryAdapter(IDynamoDbClientFactory factory) =>
        this.factory = factory;

    private async Task<IUserRepository> GetRepositoryAsync()
    {
        if (this.repository is null)
        {
            var client = await this.factory.GetClientAsync();
            this.repository = new UserRepository(client);
        }
        
        return this.repository;
    }
    
    public async Task<UserDto?> GetAsync(string hashKey, string sortKey)
    {
        var repository = await this.GetRepositoryAsync();
        return await repository.GetAsync(hashKey, sortKey);
    }

    public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(UserDto userDto)
    {
        var repository = await this.GetRepositoryAsync();
        return await repository.CreateAsync(userDto);
    }

    public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(UserDto userDto)
    {
        var repository = await this.GetRepositoryAsync();
        return await repository.UpdateAsync(userDto);
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string hashKey, string sortKey)
    {
        var repository = await this.GetRepositoryAsync();
        return await repository.DeleteAsync(hashKey, sortKey);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I'm assuming that `IAmazonDynamoDB` is not thread safe, which is why I registered `DynamicClientUserRepositoryAdapter` as scoped.

The rational of why to design things like this is explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240576/264697) you already referred to in your question.