# Can `CosmosClient.CreateAndInitializeAsync` be safely used with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-cosmosdb

I have been reading [this Microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/improve-net-sdk-initialization/) around optimizing CosmosDB initialisation.
TLDR; you can improve latency on your first few calls by using `CreateAndInitializeAsync`

As my application is hosted on AKS the pods could potentially be restarted so this optimization would be nice to have.

I would typically use `ConfigureServices` to register a singleton instance of CosmosClient in an `IServiceCollection`, however this cannot be run asynchronously. I could run `CreateAndInitializeAsync` synchronously instead but that could potentially block application start-up. A transient failure with `CreateAndInitializeAsync` could also block start-up if used here.

Is there a way of safely utilizing `CreateAndInitializeAsync` in a .NET Core Application?

Comment: Resolving instances can never be asynchronous. This is simply not something that MS.DI (or any other DI container for that matter) supports. You should, therefore, consider other options, such as hiding `CosmosDB` behind an application-specific abstraction so that you can ensure either eager loading at startup or lazy loading at runtime, without application code needing to be affected by this. See for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240576/264697).

Answer (score 1):

`CreateAndInitializeAsync` should handle transient failures correctly in order to still complete execution even if there are network conditions affecting the initialization optimization.

The only scenarios where an exception should be thrown is if the inputs to the method are invalid (for example, you are passing an empty list of Containers, or the names are null, or the authentication keys/tokens are empty).