# Async alternative to IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core-7.0

In ASP.NET Core, some dependencies require async creation. For example, Playwright can be initialised like so:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
  // ...
  var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
  var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
  var browserContext = await browser.NewContextAsync();
  services.AddSingleton(playwright);
  services.AddSingleton(browser);
  services.AddSingleton(browserContext);
  // ...
  await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

This is possible due to `async Task Main()`.

But when performed in a separate assembly or reusable library, one typically uses the pattern:

```cs
builder.AddFoo();
```

Which internally does this:

```cs
webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => /* ... */);
```

...and that is not async.

Is there an async way to register services in a separate library?

Comment: Which objects/instances in your sample code do you want to have as registered services? Your post is unclear. And to clarify, are you asking about `async` factory methods - or just wanting to run async code before `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: One of the (many) reasons why you can't have async logic in `ConfigureServices` is because (90% of the time) async methods represent an _IO boundary_ and the objects necessarily contain ephemeral state relating to that IO operation (e.g. a `NetworkStream` or open file-handle, etc), so even if you could register them, it would be very unwise to because those objects aren't intended to be stable for the entire life of the program - that's why you'd instead register a service-factory rather than the service itself, e.g. `IDbContextFactory` in EF.

Comment: @Dai I want to create `playwright`, `browser` and `browserContext` asynchronously, as in the top code block. They can only be created asynchronously. When I move that code into a separate library, there is no mechanism (which I know of) to perform such async init. I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: @Dai Thanks that's an interesting point. Is there an example of such a thing? EDIT- oh okay I'll try look into the source of IDbContextFactory.

Comment: @Dai Please see the new answer below... is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240576/9971404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a factory for those services that require async creation, then call the `Create` method for that factory instance when needed in the dependent classes.  In the case of creating an singleton, register the factory class as a singleton, then within the factory, keep track of the singleton instance it creates and return that resulting `Task<T>` for all calls to `Create`.  Simple example:

```
public PlaywriteFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<Playwrite>> _playwriteTask;

    public PlaywriteFactory( ...depenencies... )
    {
        _playwriteTask = new Lazy<Task<Playwrite>>( () =>
        {
            ... code that returns Task<Playwrite> ...
        } );
    }

    public Task<Playwrite> CreateAsync()
    {
        return _playwriteTask.Value;
    }
}

/////
services.AddSingleton<PlaywriteFactory>();

///// usage ///
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly Task<Playwrite> _playwriteTask;

    public SomeClass( PlaywriteFactory factory )
    {
        _playwriteTask = factory.CreateAsync();
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        var playwrite = await _playwriteTask;

        ...
     }
}
```

Edit: and if you have several uses for such a construct, you can easily make the factory generic

Comment: @Dai yes it should

Comment: `_playwriteTask = factory.CreateAsync();` <-- This will likely work in practice, but if `SomeClass.SomeMethod()` is never called _and_ if the `Task` failed, then your process might crash.

Comment: This isn't an exhaustive implementation, just a demonstration of how to achieve the task at hand.  The lesson is anything that doesn't fit well with DI registration should register a factory implementation instead

Comment: @Dai btw if `SomeClass.SomeMethod` is never called, the `Lazy` will never evaluate so no error will occur.  Only when a dependent class requires `Playwrite` will the `Lazy` evaluate and the user should handle problems in a standard fashion

Comment: @Dai I think I understand your concern - if the `Lazy` eval fails, then it's stuck with the result of the failure.  A proper implementation should handle such a case to recreate/retry the creation process should the initial creation fail