# How to use a async task method in a constructor?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a class in which constructor I need to use one async method. The problem is that in a constructor I can use the async keyword so I can't use the await with async method. So by the moment I am using this way:

```
Task myTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    myList.AddRange(MymethodAsync().Result.OrderBy(x => x.Name));
                });
```

But I don't know if it is the best way, wrap the method in a task.

I have tried this:

```
myList.AddRange(MymethodAsync().Result.OrderBy(x => x.Name));
```

But this block my application, it is a problem with Result.

Really I need to use in the constructor various async methods, that if I could, I would like to run in parallel and wait until all of them have finished.

Thanks.

Comment: Constructors, as their name suggest, should be used only for initialization logic. Async calls belong to methods.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479 for some suggestions.

Comment: I don't call the constructor in the async method, at contrary, I am trying to call the asyn method in the constructor of my viewmodel.

Comment: Yes, and this is what you shouldn't do