# Why can't I create an async constructor?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, nosql

In my project, I want to create a class that handles all the dirty Azure work and provide a clean interface where I simply provide entities to store.

I tried creating the table in my constructor but it does not allow it. And I cannot figure what is wrong with this construction.

Any idea or alternative way of doing things ?

Cheers,
Alex

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class AzureStorage
    {
        public async Task<AzureStorage> AzureStorage()
        {
            table = await CreateTableAsync("mytable");
        }

        CloudTable table { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, async constructors are not allowed. [This blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) written by Stephen Cleary discussed about this issue and shared some alternatives, please read it.

> *Asynchronous construction poses an interesting problem. It would be useful to be able to use await in a constructor, but this would mean
>   that the constructor would have to return a Task representing a
>   value that will be constructed in the future, instead of a constructed
>   value. This kind of concept would be very difficult to work into the
>   existing language.*

Besides, this thread: [Can constructors be async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async) would help you understand async constructor issue.