# which is the difference between task.whenAll and configurewait?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an async method that get data from a database:

```
private async Task getDataAsync()
{
    await getDataFromDatabaseAsync();
}
```

I have a contructor that uses this method, in this way:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Task.WhenAll(getDataAsync());
    //getDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    //next line of code
}
```

The only way that I get to avoid the applications isn't blocked is using one the two options, both seems to work fine. I can use WhenAll or I can use ConfigureAwait(false).

Another options it is calling the method getDataASync() inside a task, but I guess it is a worse option becase it takes more resources.

So I would like to know which is the differences between WhenAll and ConfigureAwait.

When I use WhenAll in this way, the line of code "next line of code" is run after the async method is finisihed or it will run before finish?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're just trying to get around the fact you can't call async code in a constructor. Much better to not do that and rework that code.

Comment: Task.WhenAll() will run all passed task to completion. ConfigureAwait(false) will not sync with the syncronization context when the task is completed.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` is about the synchronisation context and has nothing to do with "blocking". You are mixing asynchronous programing with parallel execution here. It's not the same thing. `Task.WhenAll` takes some tasks and lets them run as long as it takes and comes back when all are done. `await` behaves like that with one task and `ConfigureAwait` just tells it which context to use.

Comment: Is this running in a STA? e.g. WPF Dispatcher?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can constructors be async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common misconception that when you make a method `async`, it will be actually executed asynchronously (i.e. on a separate thread). That is not the case: `async` and `await` are a means to synchronize already asnychronous code. If you have nothing that is executed on a separate thread, your `async` code will run fully synchronously to the end.

Since `getDataAsync` is executed on the same thread as the `MyViewModel` constructor, you can run into a deadlock, since the thread waits for itself. When you use `ConfigureAwait`, you *can* avoid this situation.

Whether you actually *should* do that is a different question. What you are actually doing with `ConfigureAwait` is to start the task and to allow the await to continue on a separate context (which can be on a separate thread). Apart from the fact that you are not even using `await` here, continuation in a different context can become a problem when you want to execute UI operations after the await.

If you want to be sure that you can wait for `getDataAsync` in your constructor, you can use `Task.Run` to force execution in the thread pool:

```
var getDataTask = Task.Run((Func<Task>)getDataAsync);
//Do something else
getDataTask.Wait();
```

Everything you execute between `Task.Run` and the `Wait()` can run during the execution of `getDataAsync`. Whether parallelism is actually worth it here depends on what else you do until the `Wait()`.

What you are doing in the `MyViewModel` constructor is to finally synchronize all asynchronous operations and make the execution of the constructor synchronous. If you want to run that operation asynchronously, you would need to start *another* task to do it. So you should be really sure that beyond that point `async` is not required anymore. If it is, run the initialization on another `async` method, `await getDataAsync()` there and synchronize somewhere up the call chain.

Comment: But in the  constructor I can't use the await keyword. I am not sure if in the last versions of .net it is possible to do that, it could be an option for me because I could use a newer version.

Comment: for that reason you should use Activation concept - have a Command (I assume you use them, since the class is called ViewModel) and execute it once ViewModel is displayed. Do not use that in constructor.