# How can I read a file in the UI thread

Tags: c#, uwp, readfile

I have code like this but when i run it show ":

> Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread. 
>   Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run

How can i resolve this ? Thanks

```
public guchi()
{   
    string[] list = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sample.csv");

    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        var tmp = item.Split(';');
        this.Add(new guchi()
        {
           test = tmp[0],
            fun = tmp[1],
            happy = tmp[2],
            run = tmp[3],
            now = tmp[4],
            god = tmp[5],
            time = tmp[6],
            final= tmp[7],
            Pyke = tmp[8],
            Xinzhao = tmp[9]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your minimum target OS version? How did you get access to that directory?

Answer (score 2):

Or use the async version of the API.

[File.ReadAllLinesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllinesasync?view=netcore-2.1)

Also please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8145479/815938) on how to use async in constructors, since you will need to mark a method as async in order to await on the API calls.