# Is it possible to create asynchronous class construction in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am planning to do an async/await in C# Blazor class constructor method. Although this is written in Blazor it's a generic for C# so it doesn't matter.

```
public class DoctorsService : IDoctorsService
{
   private readonly IConfiguration _config;

   public DoctorsService(IConfiguration config, IClinicsDoctorsService clinicsDoctorsService)
   {
        _config = config;
        clinicsDoctorsService.GetClinicsDoctorsListAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>());
   }
}
```

If you noticed the `clinicsDoctorsService` isn't awaited using `await`, that's bc the compiler will complain that the method must be in `async Task`. If I write it like `public async Task DoctorsService()`, the compiler will complain with another issue because you cannot name a method same with the class name.

Comment: In short: No, you can't create an async ctor. Ctor's main purpose is to allocate memory and give some initial value to its fields to set up a valid state for itself. If your object instance relies on some external data then you should consider to have a ctor and async init function. You may wrap these two calls into a factory method which can be async as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can constructors be async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async)

Comment: Yeah I think it answered my question. Although I still don't know how to create that async init function, that would be another topic to talk about. If someone can point me to a topic about that, it would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

#### Sync ctor + async Init

```cs
public class DoctorsService : IDoctorsService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IClinicsDoctorsService _clinicsDoctorsService;
    private bool _isInitialized = false;

    internal DoctorsService(IConfiguration config, IClinicsDoctorsService clinicsDoctorsService)
    {
        _config = config;
        _clinicsDoctorsService = clinicsDoctorsService;
        //Set only those fields which are NOT depending on external data 
    }

    internal async Task Init()
    {
        _clinicsDoctorsService.GetClinicsDoctorsListAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>());
        _isInitialized = true;
        //Set those fields which are depending on external data
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (!_isInitialized) 
            throw new NotSupportedException("Please call Init before you call any other instance method.");
        //Some business logic goes here
    }
}
```

Please note the `internal` access modifiers.

#### Dummy factory method

```cs
public static class DoctorServiceFactory
{
    public static async Task<IDoctorsService> CreateDoctorsService(IConfiguration config, IClinicsDoctorsService clinicsDoctorsService)
    {
        IDoctorsService svc = new DoctorsService(config, clinicsDoctorsService);
        await svc.Init();
        return svc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool ! Very helpful to see, even if the Topic isnt even a Problem