# How would you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in this View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

In my current WPF project I was working without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in ViewModels however I ran into a problem where views' datagrids would load before the async functions finished getting the data which resulted in empty Datagrids. It's my first time using WPF and MVVM.

**The View Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MLaRealERP.Models;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MLaRealERP.ViewModels
{
    public class AlmacenesViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        public List<Almacen> insumos;
        
        public AlmacenesViewModel()
        {
         
            insumos = new List<Almacen>();
        }
        public async void InitializeViewModel()
        {
            
            insumos = await Funciones.GetAll<Almacen>("Almacens",App.client);
        }
    }
}
```

**The model**

```
namespace MLaRealERP.Models
{
    public class Almacen
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

**The View**

```
namespace MLaRealERP.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AlmacenesView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AlmacenesView : Window
    {
        AlmacenesViewModel AlmacenesVM;
        public AlmacenesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AlmacenesVM = new AlmacenesViewModel();
            AlmacenesVM.InitializeViewModel();
            dgInsumos.ItemsSource = AlmacenesVM.insumos;
        }

        //public async void LoadViewItems()
        //{
        //    insumos.InitializeViewModel();
        //}
        
        private void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAddInsumo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dgInsumos.ItemsSource = AlmacenesVM.insumos;
        }

        private void btnVerInsumos_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The async http request function just in case its relevant

```
public static class Funciones
    {
        public static async Task<List<T>> GetAll<T>(string s, HttpClient client)
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.IO.Stream> streamTask;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync(s);
            var repositories = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<T>>(await streamTask);
            return repositories;
        }
        public static async Task<T> Get<T>(string s, int i, HttpClient client)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            s = s + "/" + i.ToString();
            try
            {
                var item = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<T>(s);
                return item;
            }
            catch { };
            return default(T);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: `public List<Almacen> insumos;` should be an `ObservableCollection<T>` and `class Almacen` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: `public async void InitializeViewModel()` -- [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). This might also be helpful: [Can constructors be async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async)

Answer (score 1):

Your missing `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation is not the only problem (missing notification, memory leak). The original issue that the constructor continues before the `AlmacenesViewModel.InitializeViewModel` has completed is related to the way you call asynchronous methods: you must `await` them! Now that the main thread is not waiting for the `async` method to complete and the `DataGrid` is not binding to a property that raises the `PropertyChanged` event, the changes are not detected by the control.

Since a constructor can't be `async`, the constructor is the wrong place to execute `async` operations.
Usually an operation is async when it blocks the current thread. Such methods should generally not be part of the instance construction. A constructor must always return fast.

The solution is to invoke this async method deferred, e.g. using `Lazy<T>`, to initialized the corresponding property the moment they are accessed.
In case of a control you can also use the `Loaded` event to defer initialization.

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the binding source, when the mode *is not* `OneTime` or `OneWayToSource`, is essential. Otherwise you will create a memory leak. See this example to learn how to implement it properly: [INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples).

Remember that an async method should must always return a `Task` or `Task<T>`. The only exception is if the method is an event handler.

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public async Task InitializeAsync()
  {
    this.DataModels = await GetDataModelsAsync();
  }

  private List<DataModel> dataModels;
  public List<DataModel> DataModels
  {
    get => this.dataModels;
    set
    {
      this.dataModels = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
    
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
  // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
  // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
  private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private async void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    await (this.DataContext as ViewModel).InitializeAsync();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataModels}" />
</Window>
```